# Zend Admin Controller Launches Htaccess Login?

Tags: zend-framework

I have several controllers in my new app. One is called admin. For some reason, whenever I try to go to mydomain.com/admin i get a standard htaccess login screen?? I have the standard .htaccess file and everything else works which makes me think /admin has a special purpose? My controller doesn't do anything at this point. It is just:

```
class AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
    }

}
```

And I have an empty view as well. Same as the other controllers. Anyone have an idea? Did I miss something about reserved controllers or something?

BTW, the .htaccess login says something about my svn server... Could there be something in the SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. My bad. I had an svn project named admin and it was taking precedence in Apache. All fixed now.